# How would I go about making a program to click a button on a google form?

Tags: java, python, html, google-forms

It kinda says it all in the title, I'm really new to programming so its probably very simple. But I thought I should ask for help anyway just in case I don't figure it out.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Puppeteer is an option

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Your posting is out of scope in several respects.

Comment: Please try it yourself first, and then come here when you're stuck. You're essentially asking someone to write a tutorial for a broad topic.

Comment: I have tried to do this myself, but as i stated I am very new to programming. I could not find any documentation on it online. Just don't click the question if you aren't gonna answer it.. There isn't a limited number of questions the website can have...

Thank you for the people that actually tried to help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to automate browser interactions. There's multiple ways you can do this when it comes to forms, but here's 2 ways to start you off.

You can use the Requests library to send POST requests to the server. To do this you would want to use the browser inspection tools to examine the POST request that is sent when you submit your form. You then can create a program to recreate that. This is a headless approach, meaning there is no browser involved that you can physically see your programming interacting with. 
link: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Method number 2 involves writing a program that uses a library that physically interacts with a browser. For example automates your mouse movements, page scrolls, and key presses into selected inputs on the page (in your case form input fields). One of the most popular libraries to accomplish this is Selenium. To use selenium you run an instance of your browser (Firefox and Google Chrome are supported and well documented) and then you would write code to automate visiting the forms page, selecting each form field, typing the data in the fields, and then submitting the form. To figure out how to access each area of the website form, you would want to use your browser inspection tools (Firefox browser inspection tools are better than Chrome's in my opinion) and you can figure out what each field is referred to by in the html that is used to build the page... for example upon inspecting the Name field of the form, you may find something like `<form><input "id=name-field>Type your name here </input></form>` in the html. You would then use a Selenium method such as `driver.find_element_by_id('name-field')` to access the element. You could set that element to a variable like this: `name = driver.find_element_by_id('name-field')` and then use a line like this `name.send_keys("Billy Bob")` to have Selenium type "Billy Bob" into the name field.
To have a button be clicked you simply map the button to a variable like this `button = driver.find_element_by_id('button-id')` and then you would do this `button.click()`. Note that "driver" in the above example refers to the instance of the web browser that you are automating and is created at the start of the program. 
link: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html

Method #2 is probably the route you want to take as a beginner. I hope that helps get you started.